# Using two viewports with css media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries, viewport

I want to make my website responsive on iPhone screen and i'm still noob in css media query.

Right now i'm having two different css one for mobile with 320px screen and one for desktop version (1280px). 
What i want to do is to make the viewport automatically adjust to 320px when it detect the 320px screen but any size larger (>320px) will automatically use the viewport:1280px.

I manage to get the viewport dynamically change with "width=device-width" but the layout will totally screw for let say, Samsung Note 3 with 380px screen.
I want anything larger than 320px screen to adapt the 1280px viewport.

It seems the most simple thing to do but i cant get it work the way i want. Hope somebody can enlight me on this and hope my bad english is not that confusing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, **don't** use device width, it should rarely be used. A lot of people like to use viewports that are *smaller* than their device (like me!)

With that being said, you need to use either `min-width` or `max-width` for your `@media` queries. What I would recommend is doing the following, called mobile-first development

```
/* All styles for mobile (<320px) */
... All of your properties ...

@media (min-width: 320px) { /* Apply on all screen larger than 319px */
    /* Override older properties for the 1280px viewport */
    .. Your properties that override the smaller sized page properties ...
}
```

Using this method, you could use several of these in addition to each other in order to serve all screen sizes.

However, if you don't want to serve mobile first, you can do it the opposite way as well

```
/* All styles for large screen (1280px layout) */
... All of your properties ...

@media (max-width: 320px) { /* Apply on all screen smaller than 321px */
    /* Override older properties for the 320px viewport */
    .. Your properties that override the larger sized page properties ...
}
```

Again, I recommend using several of these, perhaps 3-5ish depending on your page, in order to serve all screen sizes

Comment: It depends on what you want. I can't help ya there because it's pretty irrelevant to my answer. My answer works without a meta tag but doesn't do some things that meta tags do (media queries and meta tags are different)

Comment: Ahhh i get it now. I think i will just ditch the viewport. Thanks Zach!